# How can I convert a DateTime to an int in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Asp.Net and want to convert datetime into integer format. I am getting this date from SQL.

```
> I want 2021/03/15 date into 1210315 in my application and will use it further.
> 
> Here, 1 is century, 21 is year, 03 is month, and 15 is date.
```

I have googled a lot but couldn't find any solution.
If anyone have any idea, then give its solution and your help would be appreciated.....Thanks

I am briefly describing my problem:

Here is my stored procedure

```
create proc spMaxDate
As
Begin
select max(Date) from Customer
End
```

Then in my application I have fetched the max date from this stored procedure as:

```
var SQlDate = db.spMaxDate().FirstOrDefault();
```

Here, I am getting date as 2021/03/15.
So, I have to convert it in 1210315 format as described earlier....Or If its possible to convert it in SQL select statement then you can tell.

Comment: You can not get a ready code here. Please show us your coding effort and your problem code. Then anyone can help.

Comment: Take a look at the DateTime class and the ToString method in particular.  You want a _custom format_

Comment: @Flydog57 - custom format would work, except might need some manipulation of the year to get an output of "1" to represent the century ....... or just hard-code it in the string format and assume your code won't still be being used in another 80 years .....? :)

Comment: @SJNF I have shared the code you can check it.

Comment: @Flydog57 How to create custom format, can you give me some idea to do it....Thanks

Comment: string formatedDate = "1" + dt.ToString("yyMMdd");

Comment: How does 1 represent the century? Wouldn't 20210315 be abetter representation which is well within the bounds of an int? What about dates prior to 2000? Why do you want it as a int in the first place? [Sounds like an XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JohnG Actually you are correct, but the requirement of the client is such that....and we don't  need to fetch data before 2000....It is for the latest data.....Thanks

Comment: _"and we don't need to fetch data before 2000"_ ... and this matters how?

Comment: No we have to update the database table on daily basis...So, we want only current date and not before 2000

Comment: sql  would  be SELECT '1' + FORMAT(@SQLDate,'yyMMdd')

Comment: hmmm.... `if (dt.Date > new DateTime(1999, 12, 31))  { formatedDate = "1" + dt.ToString("yyMMdd"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database you can use:

```
select (year(datecol) - 1900) * 10000 + month(datecol) * 100 + day(datecol)
```

Most databases support these functions.  In some, you need to use `extract()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The sanest way I can think of to handle this weird requirement

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; //Populate this from your db

int iDate = int.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) - 19000000;
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bruGO0)